# Proving $p(E \land F | E) \ge p(E \land F | E \lor F)$

Tags: probability-theory

$p(E \land  F | E) \ge p(E \land F | E \lor F)$

I tried to simplify each expression until I get something obvious (e.g. $ a + 1\ge a$)

My attempt was as follows:

$p(E \land  F | E) = \frac{p(E \land  F)}{ p(E)}$

that is the left expression

The right one:

$$p(E \land F | E \lor F) = \frac{p((E \land F) \land (E \lor F))}{ p(E \lor F)}= \frac{p(E \land F)}{ p(E \lor F)}$$

$(E \land F) \land (E \lor F)$ This will evaluate to $(E \land F)$ because it's a subset

That is as far as I got, I could have simplified the denominator but I don't that would do anything

Comment: Are $E$ and $F$ exclusive?

Comment: @rrogerr No, they are not.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, observe that $$P(A)\leq P(A\cup B)$$ for any $A$ and $B$ and that $$\frac{x}{y} > \frac{x}{z}$$ when $x > 0$ and $z>y>0$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

For any $E$ and $F$:

$$
P(F) - P(E \wedge F) \geq 0
$$

$$
P(E) + P(F) - P(E \wedge F) \geq P(E)
$$

$$
\frac{1}{P(E) + P(F) - P(E \wedge F)} \leq \frac{1}{P(E)}
$$

$$
\frac{1}{P(E\vee F)} \leq \frac{1}{P(E)}
$$